# How to get the verification code while registering mobile number in Twilio?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-functions

I want to get the verification code when I made a request for the registration of a new number on twilio. The call gets made and ask for the verification number but I can't see the verification number.

```html
<?php

// Update the path below to your autoload.php,
// see https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
require __DIR__ . '/twilio-php-master/Twilio/autoload.php';
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$validation_request = $twilio->validationRequests
                             ->create("+14158675310", // phoneNumber
                                      array(
                                          "friendlyName" => "My Home Phone Number"
                                      )
                             );

print($validation_request->friendlyName);
```

This is the code given on the documentation which was supposed to return the below result array. but I only get the friendly name even after trying to print entire array.

```html
{
  "account_sid": "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "call_sid": "CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "friendly_name": "My Home Phone Number",
  "phone_number": "+14158675310",
  "validation_code": 100
}
```

**Note** :- I used my original values for each variable and also tried to print entire array of $validation_request but it was of no use.

May be I am missing something minor. Any help is accepted. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The code snippet you shared ends with

```
print($validation_request->friendlyName);
```

Which should just show the friendly name you created the number validation request with. If you want the validation code you should look at:

```
print($validation_request->validationCode);
```

Let me know if that helps.